# check boxes and text area with mechanize

Tags: drop-down-menu, mechanize, checkbox, python-2.6

I have a html form with java-script which contain text fields,drop-down menu and check boxes. I want to fill that html form with python code. Form has two button one is "Apply" and second is "submit changes", first click on apply then submit changes.
HTML code is like that:

```
<form id="my_form" action="/temp/var/index" method="POST">
<fieldset id="my_fieldset" style="width:1330px">

   <h3 style="margin:1px;margin-left:20px;"> MY Form <div class='helps' id='helpform'> </div></h3>
   <p><label for="help_no" id="label_help" class="help_code" style="width:80px;margin:1px;float:left;text-align:right;">add a Help:</label>
   <input type="text" name="help_no" id="help_no" class="text ui-corner-all help_code" style="width:100px;margin:1px;float:left;"/>
   <label for="helptype" id="label_helptype" class="help_code" style="width:60px;margin:1px;float:left;text-align:right;">Help type:</label>
   <select id='helptype' class=" ui-widget-context help_code" style="width:100px;margin:1px;float:left;">
         <option value="PHelp">Help1</option>
        <option value="THelp">Help2r</option>
        <option value="IHelp">Help3r</option>
   </select>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="comment" id="comment"  class=" ui-corner-all help_code" style="margin:1px;margin-left:20px;float:left;"/>
  <label for="comment" id="label_commment" class="help_code" style="margin:1px;margin-left:3px;clear:left;" >add comment to Helps</label></p>
  <p><input type='button' id='btn_code' style="width:120px;float:left;margin:10px;margin-top:2px;" value='Apply' disabled/>
  <p><label style="float:left;margin:1px;text-align:left;color:red;font-weight:bold;">Note:Select results from table, input help information and click Apply.Finally, click Submit Changes.</label></p>
  <input type='button' id='btn_submit' style="width:120px;float:right;margin:10px;" value='Submit Changes' disabled /> </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I have tried with:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open('http://myform.com/')
br.select_form(name="my_form")
br['help_no']='12345'

res = br.submit()
```

but i don't know how to set the value for drop-down menu and check boxes.
if any better way to do this, please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the selected `form`:

```
br.form['help_no'] = '12345'
br.form['helptype'] = ['THelp'] #  a list, so you could have multiple selected
br.form.find_control('comment').items[0].selected = True
```